# How to make nil produces simple empty string in NSStringWithFormat?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

```
    NSString * strNil= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",nil];
```

The result is strNil is @"null"

Well, I want it to be @""

And I want an elegant solution. I know I can just create emptyStringIfNil category method. But that wouldn't work because that function will return nil, instead of @"".

What do you do for this?

Basically I want statements like

```
NSString * result =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/business/api/addOrEditBusiness.php?flag=%@&title=%@&building=%@&latitude=%@&longitude=%@&website=%@&street=%@&city=%@&country=%@%@&originalid=%@&inbuildingaddress=%@&email=%@&zip=%@%@&userid=%@%@",urlServer,strFlag,biz.Title.RobustURLEncodedString,biz.buildingName.RobustURLEncodedString,@(coord.latitude),@(coord.longitude),biz.Website.RobustURLEncodedString,biz.Street.RobustURLEncodedString, biz.City.Name.RobustURLEncodedString, biz.City.Country.Name.RobustURLEncodedString,strPhonesParameter,biz.ID.RobustURLEncodedString,biz.InBui
```

to show empty everytime the string is nil

For example, if streetAddress is nil, I want &street=&city=Tokyo instead &street=(null)&city=Tokyo

Comment: Why would your `emptyStringIfNil` category method return `nil`? If you write it such as: `return string ? string : @"";` then you get what you want.

Comment: if he calls `[anObject emptyStringIfNil]` and `anObject` is nil, the method returns nil.

Comment: @Sebastian Good point. That isn't an issue if `emptyStringIfNil` is written as a function instead of an instance method. And that's what your answer shows. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a C function instead:

```
static inline NSString* emptyStringIfNil(NSString *s) {
    return s ? s : @"";
}
```

Then `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", emptyStringIfNil(nil)]` returns an empty string.

You could also add a class method to `NSString`, but I personally like the C approach better.

```
@interface NSString (EmptyIfNil)
+ (NSString*)emptyStringIfNil:(NSString*)s;
@end

@implementation NSString (EmptyIfNil)
+ (NSString*)emptyStringIfNil:(NSString*)s {
    return s ? s : @"";
}
@end
```

And then use `[NSString emptyStringIfNil:yourString]`

Answer (score 7):

I dont know if there is an easier way, but you could just put:

```
(strName ? strName : @"")
```

or, more simply put you can use:

```
strName?:@""
```

which does the exact same thing.

for each of the strings, which will just place the string in your output if it is not nil, otherwise an empty string.

Comment: It's a GCC extension (and thus Clang has it too).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSString *strNil1 = [[NSString alloc] init];
strNil1 = @"1";
strNil1  = strNil1 ? strNil1 : @"";
NSLog(@" ==> %@", strNil1);
```

Output :: **`==> 1`**

```
NSString *strNil2 = [[NSString alloc] init];

strNil2  = strNil2 ? strNil2 : @"";
NSLog(@" ==> %@", strNil2);
```

Output :: **`==>`**

Hope, you'll get it.

Thanks.